# find minimum for each name and return the according row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looks like

```
name val Info
a 1.1 'Info_a1.1'
a 0.1 'Info_a0.1'
b 0.2 'Info_b0.2'
a 0.3  ...
b 0.4
c 0.4
c 0.5
```

I want to find the minimum val for each name, and return the rows (unique one is enought) looks like

```
name val Info
a 0.1 'Info_a0.1'
b 0.2 'Info_b0.2'
c 0.4 'Info_c0.4'
...
```

How can I do that.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow for "split-apply-combine".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, list(val = min(val), Info = Info[which.min(val)]), by = name] # dat is your data set

##   name val      Info
##1:    a 0.1 Info_a0.1
##2:    b 0.2 Info_b0.2
##3:    c 0.4 Info_c0.4
```